# how to update user phone number in firebase.auth (js, ts)

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

How can i update user phone number which it use for auth in firebase.auth??

Firebase give as method:

```
updatePhoneNumber(phoneCredential)
```

But we need give  **phoneCredential**. 
This credential takes object:

```
  interface AuthCredential {
    providerId: string;
    signInMethod: string;
  }
```

What must be in this **phoneCredential**, i try to send

```
providerId: 'phone';
signInMethod: 'phone';
```

and this is not work ;(

Comment: Could you clarify what is the error you're getting please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the credential from `firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential`.

```
    // Send verification code to user's phone
    firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchVerifier).then(function(verificationId) {
      // verification code from user
      var cred = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode);
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

The solution to updatePhoneNumber with a current user / logged-in account. In case this helps anyone.

problem:
Say you have a current logged in account with any number of single/merged accounts and they want to update their number. How would they do it.

solution:
The below is Auth for Web/JS method, the equivalent will exist for your target platform.

```
function updateProfilePhoneNumber() {
    //country code plus your phone number excluding leading 0 if exists.
    var phoneNumber = "+447xxxxxxxxx"; //you could provide a prompt/modal or other field in your UX to replace this phone number.

    // let phoneNumber = "+441234567890"; //testing number, ideally you should set this in your firebase auth settings
    // var verificationCode = "123456";

    // Turn off phone auth app verification.
    // firebase.auth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;

    // This will render a fake reCAPTCHA as appVerificationDisabledForTesting is true.
    // This will resolve after rendering without app verification.
    var appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
        "recaptcha-container",
        {
            size: "invisible"
        }
    );

    var provider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
    provider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then(function (verificationId) {
            var verificationCode = window.prompt('Please enter the verification ' +
                'code that was sent to your mobile device.');
            phoneCredential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode);
            user.currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(phoneCredential);
        })
        .then((result) => {
            // Phone credential now linked to current user.
            // User now can sign in with new phone upon logging out.
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Error occurred.
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Happy to be corrected here.

Comment: Great, it works, thx

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**: I edited my previous answer as I now think it was far from being right. After researching a bit more, I believe you need to use the built in [PhoneAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider) to update the user phone number, like below:

```
const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential( verificationId, verificationCode);

user.updatePhoneNumber(credential);
```

**Original (wrong)**: According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthCredential), you need to pass an object with the **methods** that will return the providerId, signInMethod (which [should](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider#PHONE_SIGN_IN_METHOD) be phone, as in your code) and smsCode (the sms verification code that was sent to the user mobile as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth)). Give it a try like that:

```
updatePhoneNumber({
  getProvider: () => { return providerStringCode; },
  getSignInMethod: () => { return signInMethodStringCode; },
  getSmsCode: () => { return smsStringCode; },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same problem, 
In my html page(using ionic 4 modal), I have 2 button send OTP & verify.
So this is my solution

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Edit Phone</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <form [formGroup]="phoneForm">
        <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="stacked" >Phone :</ion-label>
          <ion-input
            formControlName="phoneNumber"
            type="tel"
            required="true"
            [class.invalid]="!phoneForm.controls['phoneNumber'].valid && phoneForm.controls['phoneNumber'].touched">
          </ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item 
          class="error-message" 
          *ngIf="!phoneForm.controls['phoneNumber'].valid && phoneForm.controls['phoneNumber'].touched">
            <ion-label>Phone Number.</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <div id="recaptcha-container" visibility="hidden"></div>
        
        <ion-button id="sign-in-button" *ngIf="!btnSend" (click)="editPhone(phoneForm)" expand="block" [disabled]="!phoneForm.valid" data-badge="inline">SMS OTP</ion-button>
        <ion-button id="sign-in-button" *ngIf="btnSend" expand="block" [disabled]="btnSend" data-badge="inline">{{timeLeft}}</ion-button>
        
       

    </form>
</ion-card>


<ion-card>
    <form [formGroup]="verificationForm">
    <ion-item>
        
          <ion-label position="stacked">
            OTP : 
          </ion-label>
              <ion-input formControlName="verificationCode" type="tel" >
          </ion-input>
       
        
    </ion-item>
        <ion-button (click)="verifyPhoneCode()" expand="block" [disabled]="!verificationForm.valid||!verificationSend">
            Verifikasi
        </ion-button>
  </form>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

```
sendOTP(){
firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithPhoneNumber(this.telepon,this.recaptchaVerifier)
    .then(result=>{

      this.confirmationResult = result;//firebase.auth.ConfirmationResult


    })
    .catch(error=>{
      this.presentErrorMessage(error.message);
    });
}

verifyPhoneNumber(){
    let phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
            phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(this.telepon, this.recaptchaVerifier)//this.telepon is your new phone number
                 .then(verificationId=>{
                    let phoneCredential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, this.verificationForm.value.verificationCode);
                    firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(phoneCredential)
                    .then(()=>{
                      console.log("Success update phone");
                      this.authService.updatePhone(this.telepon).then(()=>{ //update my user database
                          this.dismiss(); //I'm using modal dialog for input
                        });
                    });
                  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to add a phone number to an existing, logged-in user (`verifyPhoneNumber`):

```
const appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('save-user-button', { size: 'invisible' }) // An element with id="save-user-button" must exist
const authProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider()
const verificationId = await authProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
const verificationCode = window.prompt('Please enter the verification code that was sent to your phone.')
const phoneCredential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode)
myFirebaseUser.updatePhoneNumber(phoneCredential)
```

Sign up/create new user from phone number (`signInWithPhoneNumber`):

```
const appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('create-new-user-button', { size: 'invisible' }) // An element with id="create-new-user-button" must exist
const confirmationResult = await firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
const verificationCode = window.prompt('Please enter the verification code that was sent to your phone.')
const { user } = await confirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth