# FIREBASE phoneAuth ( LinkWithPhoneNumber ) . How to change a user's linked phone number later in Firebase Web. ( nodejs, Create-react-app )?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, create-react-app

I am using firebase in my create-react-app project.
For SignUp purpose I am using 
`firebaseAuth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

Then after SignUp I am saving their phoneNumber in localStorage and redirect them to PhoneAuth page using then I am using this function

```
export function PhnAuth(phone) {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebaseAuth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container',{'size': 'small'});
    return firebaseAuth().currentUser.linkWithPhoneNumber(phone, window.recaptchaVerifier)
    .then(function (confirmationResult) {
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      }).catch(function (error) {
    })
}
```

After the recaptcha and all done I get the I successfully linked the user's email with their phoneNumber. But how to update that phoneNumber later ? I couldn't find anything regarding updating a linked phoneNumber in the docs.

Comment: you can update user object and assign phone number to it, or call updatePhoneNumber function later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an `updatePhoneNumber` method on the `User` object for that purpose.

See the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updatePhoneNumber) and the [documentation on updating a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).

Note that you'll need a `phoneCredential` for this, meaning that this must be a verified phone number. See [how to update user phone number in firebase.auth (js, ts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942415/how-to-update-user-phone-number-in-firebase-auth-js-ts).

If you want to update a user's phone number without verifying it, that can be done from the Admin SDK. For an example of this, see [How to update phone number on Firebase Authentication in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225793/how-to-update-phone-number-on-firebase-authentication-in-nodejs)

Comment: Yeah. Got it. I wasn't getting the part about passing the phone auth credential. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unlink the current phone `(provider.providerId === 'phone')`
Then you can link a new one

```js
    const currentUser = firebaseAuth().currentUser;

    currentUser.unlink('phone').then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback)
```

To check if the phone is linked to the current user you need to check the list of providers

```js
    const phoneProviders = currentUser.providerData.filter(
      provider => provider.providerId === 'phone'
    );
    if (phoneProviders.length > 0) {
      currentUser.unlink('phone').then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback);
    }
```